# Rest API: Get order id by customer email

Tags: magento-1.7, api, rest-api, soap-api-v2

Can I get list of orders by customer email (as input) via Rest API?

I do not want to create any special extensions for Magento. I use Magento 1.7.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is possibility to orders by specified criteria. More information you can find in [Official Magento Docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/get_filters.html).

In order to filter orders by customer email, try with:

`http://magento.local/api/rest/orders?filter[1][attribute]=customer_email&filter[1][eq]=your@email.com`